# ROS move_base node is generating pre-Hydro warning

Tags: c++, navigation, ros, robotics, catkin

I am working with move_base from navigation stack. However, I am getting the warning that

"local_costmap: preHydro parameter "static_map" unused since "plugins" is provided"

In terms of costmap definition here are the common and local config files I have been using:

```
footprint: [ [-0.15,-0.15], [0.15,-0.15], [0.15,0.15], [-0.15,0.15] ]
transform_tolerance: 0.5
map_type: costmap
obstacle_layer:
 enabled: true
 obstacle_range: 3.0
 raytrace_range: 3.5
 inflation_radius: 0.2
 track_unknown_space: false
 combination_method: 1
 observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: scanmatcher_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: false}
inflation_layer:
  enabled:              true
  cost_scaling_factor:  1.0  
  inflation_radius:     0.2
obstacle_layer:
     enabled: true
     obstacle_range: 5.0
     raytrace_range: 1.0
     observation_sources: "/scan"
     observation_persistence: 0.0
     inf_is_valid: false
     scan:
       data_type: LaserScan
       topic: scan

local_costmap:
 global_frame: map
 robot_base_frame: base_link
 update_frequency: 0.5
 publish_frequency: 0.25
 static_map: false
 rolling_window: true
 width: 50
 height: 50
 width: 8
 height: 8
 origin_x: -4
 origin_y: -4
 resolution: 0.1
 transform_tolerance: 0.5 
 plugins:
   - {name: inflation_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
```

Now, I have followed the navigation tutorial page which exactly addresses this issue but without success. Interestingly,my global costmap throws the same warning while receiving the map correctly with a message that "Recieved a 250x250 map at 0.1 m/px". My global yaml file looks like this:

```
global_costmap:
 global_frame: map
 robot_base_frame: base_link
 update_frequency: 0.5
 publish_frequency: 0.25
 always_send_full_costmap: true
 width: 250
 height: 250
 origin_x: -125
 origin_y: -125
 resolution: 0.1
 static_map: true
 plugins:
   - {name: static_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static_map` parameter has been deprecated and is no longer used.

Just remove the `static_map: false` line inside the `local_costmap` parameters to make the warning go away.

Comment: Thanks. Would you maybe have a look at the following issue as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61379723/recovery-behavior-clears-the-obstacle-layer